# Is Quotient Ring algebraic

Tags: ring-theory

Let $K$ be a field and $x$ an indeterminate. Prove that the quotient ring $K[x]/(x^2)$ is algebraic. Also prove that the ring of polynomials $K[x]$ is not algebraic.

Comment: What do you mean by algebraic?

Comment: Sharpening Servaes question: what is "an algebraic ring"?

Comment: Let A be an algebra.An element 'a' in A is said to be algebraic if there exists a non zero polynomial 'f' in K[x] such that f(a)=0.If every element in A is algebraic then A is said to be algebraic.

Comment: Then it is "algebraic **over** something", @user154570

Comment: So with this definition, can you tell whether the indeterminate $X$ algebraic over $K$ in these algebras?

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

The set $\{1,x,x^2,\dots\} $ is a basis for $K[x]$ as a $K$-algebra, hence $K[x]$ is infinite dimensional as a $K$- vector space. While the set $\{1+(x^2),x+(x^2)\}$ forms a basis for $K[x]/(x^2)$ as a $K$- vector space.